# how to get billing information for each resources of Azure ruby or by API ??

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-sdk-ruby

I tried to access through the API call **Get price and metadata information for resources used in an Azure subscription**

But the authentication is not happening through the URL request

_https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription_id/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview_

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Have you included the access token you got from Azure AD as part of your request's `Authorization` header?

Comment: @GauravMantri: Yes i have include it and tried to access it in https://www.hurl.it/ by adding access token in the header  section but its giving error..!!! message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."

Answer (score 0):

You must include the access token with the foramt "Bearer *token-string*" in the request's `Authorization` header. Also, please specify valid values for OfferDurableId, Currency, Locale and RegionInfo in format of $filter(Please note that all 4 query parameters are required).

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx for details.